# Simple Angular Slideshow: cannot trigger a click event on input type="radio"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, setinterval, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I can do this in otherways in less than ten lines of code but I want the Angular Way only. Any suggestions and methods are welcome.

i have some images and a set of radio input buttons that control which is shown here:

CSS:

```
.slide {
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide.showSlide {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="slideshow" ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderObjectBy:'sort'" sort-order="{{slide.sort}}" class="slide" ng-class="{ 'showSlide': $index == selectedIndex }"><img ng-src="{{slide.src}}" alt="{{slide.alt}}" /></div>
    <aside id="slideControls" ng-model="slides.input">
        <input ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderObjectBy:'sort'" name="{{slide.alt}}" class="slideCtrl"  type="radio" ng-click="slideShow($index)" />
    </aside>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('sliderCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $element, $interval) {
    $http.get('data/slides.json')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.slides = data;
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
        $scope.slideShow = function ($index) {
            console.log($index);
            $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
        }
        var theShow;
        $scope.$watch("slides.input", function(value) {
            var i = 1,
                iMax = $element.children(0).children('.slideCtrl').length - 1,
                elements = $element.children(0).children('.slideCtrl');
            theShow = $interval(function() {
                $scope.slideShow(i);
                if (i<iMax) i++;
                else i = 0; 
            }, 3000);   
        }); 
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data+', '+status+', '+headers+', '+config);
    });
});
```

EDITED:

SO I implemented the slideshow the way someone suggested but it still doesn't achieve what I am going for. Basically, instead of invoking the ng-click function I also need it to select my radio button as well thus I need it to actually trigger the click event on the radio button itself. I was able to target the elements to get the length but when I tried:

```
$scope.slideShow(i).triggerhandler('click');
```

I get back >>> Cannot read property 'triggerHandler' of undefined

Comment: don´t see a need to trigger click when you can manually call slideShow. Unless the controller gets called only once, I wouldn´t put the slideShow and interval inside .success

Comment: Post a solution below and if it makes sense I will mark it correct

Comment: Made the changes based your input but still not achieving the goal. See edit above

Comment: your ´slideShow´ function does not return anything, so it returns undefined and you can't so undefined.triggerhandler

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all the slide controls every second. And you probably want to loop through each slide control once a second. This is probably what your want to do:

```
var counter = 0;
var sliderOn = $interval(function() {
    var tar = angular.element('#slideControls');
    counter = (counter < tar.children.length) ? counter+1 : 0;          
    console.log(tar.children[counter]);
    // Click code goes here I suppose
}, 1000);
```

Comment: console.log returns undefined

Comment: Made some adjustments based on your feedback but still not achieving the goal. See edits above